# How to add margin between columns with Drupal Bootstrap View Grid

Tags: views, 7, theming, bootstrapping

I need help I'm trying to add some margin between columns using drupal [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) module the grid view but the columns are closed together. How can I add margin between columns. I have tried through the module settings but there isn't any option to. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can rewrite the results and add a class to all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only CSS for this, look for the columns classes and then add it in a CSS file that is loaded on your page.